# Endomorphism algebra of a coherent sheaf is locally free

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, vector-bundles

What is an example of a Noetherian ring $A$ and a finitely generated $A$-module $M$ such that the endomorphism algebra $\mathrm{Hom}_{A}(M,M)$ is flat as an $A$-module but $M$ is not flat?

Comment: Let $A$ be $k[x,y]$, and let $M$ be the ideal $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: @JasonStarr How do I show that $\mathrm{Hom}_{A}(M,M)$ is flat? I guess $M$ is not flat since it has rank 1 but the fiber above the origin has dimension 2.

Comment: Probably the fastest way to compute $\text{Hom}_A(M,M)$ in the example I propose is to use a free presentation of $M$ arising from the Koszul complex of the regular sequence $(x,y)$.  The outcome is that the natural map $A\to \text{Hom}_A(M,M)$ is an isomorphism of $A$-modules.  Thus, $\text{Hom}_A(M,M)$ is a free $A$-module of rank $1$.